# Pyramid self.request.POST is empty - no post data available

Tags: python, forms, http-post, pyramid

I'm currently working on a pyramid project, however I can't seem to submit POST data to the app from a form.

I've created a basic form such as:

```
    <form method="post" role="form" action="/account/register">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@domain.com">
        <p class="help-block">Your email address will be used as your username</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Other items removed -->
</form>
```

and I have the following route config defined:

```
    # projects __init__.py file
config.add_route('account', '/account/{action}', request_method='GET')
config.add_route('account_post', '/account/{action}', request_method='POST')

# inside my views file
@view_config(route_name='account', match_param="action=register", request_method='GET', renderer='templates/account/register.jinja2')
def register(self):
    return {'project': 'Register'}

@view_config(route_name='account_post', match_param="action=register", request_method='POST', renderer='templates/account/register.jinja2')
def register_POST(self):
    return {'project': 'Register_POST'}
```

Now, using the debugger in PyCharm as well as the debug button in pyramid, I've confirmed that the initial `GET` request to view the form is being processed by the *register* method, and when I hit the submit button the `POST` request is processed by the *register_POST* method.

However, my problem is that debugging from within the *register_POST* method, the `self.request.POST` dict is empty. Also, when I check the debug button on the page, the POST  request is registered in the list, but the POST data is empty.

Am I missing something, or is there some other way of access POST data?

Cheers, 
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does nothing, I belive.

```
return {'project': 'Register_POST'}
```

POST parameters are stored inside request, so you have to do something like this.

```
def register_POST(self, request):
     return {'project': request.POST}
```

To access email input (which has to be named, for example: `name="email"`), use `get()` method:

```
request.POST.get('email')
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, coming from a .NET background, I forgot the absolute basics of form submissions, and that's to add the name="" attribute. I only had id's specified. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get it working. Silly me, coming from an ASP.NET background forgot the basics of POST form submissions, and that's each form field needs a name== attribute. As soon as I put them in, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form method="post" role="form" action="/account/register"> {% csrf_token %}
```

Try using "csrf token". hope it works. remaining code looks fine.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. I couldn't actually get that additional piece of markup to work. I got an 'Encountered unknown tag 'csrf_token'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'.' error from that. It did however point to setting up the session and added the CSRF value to the form, but so far it's had no effect even with the CSRF value in a hidden field using this example: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/sessions.html#using-the-session-get-csrf-token-method